# Making form filling faster, using autofilling form controls(the autocomplete attribute)

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, autofill

I am working on a html form where, user can store their billing and shipping form. After reading this article [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en), I am trying to use these attributes but it is not working in chrome v-47. I am only using the provided attributes eg of shipping form:

```
<input autocomplete="given-name"  autofocus  id="ship_first_name" type="text"  name="ship_first_name" value="" data-attr-ascii = "true" required/>
<input autocomplete="shipping tel"  id="ship_telephone_no"  type="text" name="ship_telephone_no" value="" data-attr-ascii = "true" required/>
<input autocomplete="shiiping address-line2" id="ship_address_line2" type="text"  name="ship_address_line2" value="'" data-attr-ascii="true"/>
<input autocomplete="family-name" id="ship_last_name" type="text"  name="ship_last_name" value="" data-attr-ascii = "true" required/>
<input autocomplete="shiiping address-line1" id="ship_address_line1" type="text"  name="ship_address_line1" value=" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
<input autocomplete="shipping postal-code" id="ship_zip_code" type="text" name="ship_zip_code" value="data-attr-ascii = "true" required/>
```

Same, I am using for billing as well but when I am checking these attributes it is not working. It wont giving the option for select the value from browser autofill options. My autofill options are enable. Even after putting the same entered name, it is not populating the rest of the html fields. Some one please suggestion, where i am doing mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You misspelled `shipping` in several of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have several typos in the form.

Before `address-line1` and `address-line2` you spelled `shipping` as `shiiping`.

In `ship_address_line1` and `ship_zip_code` you only have one doublequote after `value=`, so the rest of the form is being parsed incorrectly.

Chrome apparently requires the inputs to be in a `<form>` for it to perform auto-fill.

```html
<form>
  <input autocomplete="given-name" autofocus id="ship_first_name" type="text" name="ship_first_name" value="" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
  <input autocomplete="shipping tel" id="ship_telephone_no" type="text" name="ship_telephone_no" value="" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
  <input autocomplete="shipping address-line2" id="ship_address_line2" type="text" name="ship_address_line2" value="'" data-attr-ascii="true" />
  <input autocomplete="family-name" id="ship_last_name" type="text" name="ship_last_name" value="" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
  <input autocomplete="shipping address-line1" id="ship_address_line1" type="text" name="ship_address_line1" value="" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
  <input autocomplete="shipping postal-code" id="ship_zip_code" type="text" name="ship_zip_code" value="" data-attr-ascii="true" required/>
</form>
```

Comment: Yup, my all the inputs are wrapped inside form tag.

Comment: I get autofill for this form in Chrome 47.